# Как в последнем методе реализовать проверку?

Tags: java, android

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {

boolean number;
boolean name;
boolean Email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
}

public void BackToLogin(View view)
{
Intent BackToLogin = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(BackToLogin);
}

private boolean CheckPhoneNumber()
{
TextView hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NumberTextView);
EditText checkPhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number);
String phoneNumber = checkPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
if (phoneNumber.length()<8 || phoneNumber.length()>20)
{
    hint.setText("You enter wrong phone number. Try again");
    checkPhoneNumber.setText("");
    return number = false;
}
else
{
    return number = true;
}
}
private boolean CheckEmail()
{
TextView Hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.EmailTextView);
EditText checkEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
String email = checkEmail.getText().toString();
if (email.matches("@") & email.matches("."))
{
    Email = true;
    return Email;
}
else
{
    Email = false;
    Hint.setText("You enter wrong E-mail. It must contains symbol '@' and '.'");
    return Email;
}
}
private boolean CheckName()
{
TextView Hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
EditText checkName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
String Name = checkName.getText().toString();
if (Name.length()<3)
{
    Hint.setText("Your name must contains more than 3 symbols");
    name = false;
    return name;
}
else
{
    name = true;
    return name;
}
}
public void GiftActivity(View view)
{
TextView Hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Hint);

if (name == false && Email == false && number == false)
{
    Hint.setText("You enter something wrong. Please, check again.");
}
else
{
    Intent GiftActivity = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, GiftHomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(GiftActivity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
if (name == false && Email == false && number == false)
```

В этом месте логичнее использовать оператор `||` (или). У вас ошибка покажется только если все три переменные `false`.

2.

```
Hint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Hint);
```

Такие вещи лучше делать в `onCreate` методе